# Multiple Embedded Images in mail with different url (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, email

Hi I am trying to create a Macro which can send mail with multiple embedded images. I want to add different url in each image and embed it as a single image in a table. Once the user click on these different part of single image it should direct him to it's respective website. Please help me with the vba macro code.

I want the said code as an extension of my code in below given question or code pasted here.

[How to Change width and height of embedded image in mail using Cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195048/how-to-change-width-and-height-of-embedded-image-in-mail-using-cell-values)

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SendMail()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object



For I = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


End With


With olMail
.To = Cells(I, 2).Value
.cc = Cells(I, 3).Value
.bcc = Cells(I, 4).Value
.Subject = Cells(I, 5).Value
.Body = Cells(I, 6).Value


On Error Resume Next
.Attachments.Add Cells(I, 7).Value
.HTMLBody ="<HTML><center> <img src ="""&Cells(I,10).Value&"""width="""&Cells(I, 8).Value&""" height=""" & Cells(I, 9).Value & """ ><br>"


On Error GoTo 0

.Display
.Send

End With

Next

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

 MsgBox "Mails Sent Successfully"


End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the error/problem? - `On Error Resume Next` hides important error details: remove it.  Using an `<img>` tag is not embedding an image, its linking to one - which many email clients will block without user interaction.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the valuable inputs. If i remove <img> what should be my code to pick image from my the path on my pc

Comment: @Rehaan: Here is the code you can use to attach a picture to your email and embed it into your HTML email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058862/how-to-embed-image-placed-inside-the-excel-into-the-htmlbody-of-vbascript/36060411#36060411

Comment: Thanks Ralph, but as pointed out by Alex that that " Using an <img> tag is not embedding an image, its linking to one - which many email clients will block without user interaction" i wanted to know the alternate code so that e-mail application should not block my image. And also would like to have code for the description given in my above question. "Multiple Embedded Images in mail with different url (Excel VBA)"

Comment: before you spend so much time trying to do this, did you consider the user experience?  how will the email recipient even know that different parts of the image have different links?  You can't have hover effects in email as far as I know.  Also, the chances that everyone's email clients will even display the image, whether embedded or linked, is slim to nil. [This post may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713626/hover-image-animate-in-news-letter-email)

Comment: @Chris M Image say "Click Here to Enrol", "Download PDF" etc. Which should have it's respective link.

Comment: Please somebody help

Comment: Please somebody help